# Use XMLEXISTS on a TEXT column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I want to execute a query on a `text` column which contains XML content, using XPATH with XMLEXISTS function. for example:

```
select * from om_table tb
WHERE xmlexists('//town[text() = ''Toronto'']' PASSING BY REF tb.config_xml);
```

which config_xml is a `text` column. But it gets error:

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.xmlexists(unknown, text) does not exist

I've also tested it on a `character varying` column, but it gets error too:

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.xmlexists(unknown, character varying) does not exist

But if i use a hard coded XML value, it executes successfully:

```
select * from om_table tb
WHERE 
xmlexists('//town[text() = ''Toronto'']' PASSING BY REF '<towns><town>Toronto</town><town>Ottawa</town></towns>');
```

What should i do? (I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.6`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert your text to [the XML type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-xml.html), using eg. `XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT tb.config_xml)` like in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9f0fb/7/0

You could also consider making `config_xml` an XML column instead of a text column.

Comment: My `text` column containing number (not a real XML), and it gets error:
ERROR:  invalid XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
18209
^

Comment: @united Why are you using XML functions on something which isn't XML? What behaviour would you expect?

Comment: @IMSoP I stored XML content in `text` column, but `postgresql` show me number instead of it. I can access it's content with something like this:
`convert_from(loread(lo_open(tb.config_xml::int, x'40000'::int), x'40000'::int),  'UTF8')`. Is it the only way?

Comment: @united Then that's not a text column, it's a [Large Object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/largeobjects.html); however, the answers still apply that you need to convert the text to XML once you've extracted it from the BLOB.

Comment: @united What IMSoP wrote, but it's quite likely that you don't really want to store your XML as large objects at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your `config_xml` is of type `text`, but your literal when you're testing is of type `xml`.

This is because of something which took me a while to get used to: single-quoted literals in Postgres *are not considered text/varchar values*, but are in fact "literals of unknown type". A column, on the other hand, always has a fixed type.

The planner will infer the type where it can; in the context of `xmlexists('//foo' PASSING BY REF '<foo />')` the only function which matches takes an argument of type `xml`, so `'<foo />'` is interpreted as an `xml` literal. This is *not* the same as casting the value from `text` to `xml`, just as writing the literal `123` is not the same as casting the string `'123'` to int.

To declare the type of a literal directly, you use the syntax `type 'value'`, so in this case the correct explicit form would be `xmlexists(text '//foo' PASSING BY REF xml '<foo />')`. If you instead wrote `xmlexists(text '//foo' PASSING BY REF text '<foo />')` you would get the same error you got when using your `text` column.

To fix this, you should either convert your column to be of type `xml` rather than `text`, or cast the value when calling the function, [as described in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html#idm46428712088032):

> To produce a value of type xml from character data, use the function xmlparse:
>   `XMLPARSE ( { DOCUMENT | CONTENT } value)`
>   Examples:
>   `XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chapter>...</chapter></book>')`
>   `XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>')`